# YQL query to get country dialing code?

Tags: yql

Is there a way using YQL to query for a country's dialing code (ie, the USA and Canada have +1)?

Comment: Do you just want the first grouping digit or both primary and secondary? For example The US and the Virgin Islands use calling code +1 as the first group but the US doesn't have a secondary and the Virgin Islands uses 340.